# How to store the values of a JSON response to an API Call in as many variables as the (unknown) number of objects using node.js

Tags: node.js, json, api, parsing

I'm creating an integration between two software, and I need to get data from software1 to post it to software2.

What I try to do is (do not hesitate if it is not the best way to do it):

First, create an API call to GET the data from software1.
Second, store the values of the JSON response in variables
Finally, use these variables to POST it back to software2

The problem is: the JSON response from API call to software 1 can contain an unknown number of objects. (Sometime it could be just, sometime it could be 2,3,...,10 or more)

So how could I create as many variables as I need to store all this data and be able to reuse it after?

I have built a program using node.js

I think I have something that makes sense if there would have only one object in the JSON response, but I need help to scale it so it could manage any number of objects.

View my code below

Here is an example of JSON response from the software1

```
[
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  }
]
```

But sometime it could have more than one object

```
[
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program2",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 2",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  }
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 1",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  }
]
```

Note that the only values that I'm interested to store are "id" and "title"

Here's the nodejs module I use:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const NodeCache = require('node-cache');
const session = require('express-session');
const delay = require('delay');
```

Here's my code

```
//====================================================//
//   Get a list of programs from software1            //
//====================================================//

const getPrograms = async () => {
  console.log('Retrieving programs');

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `Api-Key: xxxxxx`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  const programs = { 
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.software1.com/1.6/programs/',
  headers: headers,
  json: true 
  };

  request(programs)
  .then(function (parsedBody) {
    console.log(parsedBody);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err);
  });

// Store programs data in reusable variables
// THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP TO CREATE AS MANY VARIABLES AS OBJECTS IN THE JSON RESPONSE
  const programObj = JSON.parse(parsedBody);
  const programId = programObj.id;
  const programTitle = programObj.title;
};

//====================================================//
//   Post the list of programs in software2           //
//====================================================//

// Creating a contact property in software2 to store programs from the list retrieved from software1 

const createPrograms = async (accessToken) => {
  console.log('Creating a property named programs');

const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

const program = {
  headers: headers,
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://api.software2.com/properties/v1/contacts/properties',
  body: {
      name: 'programs',
      label: 'Programs',
      description: 'programs in which the contact is enrolled',
      groupName: 'group_of_properties',
      type: 'enumeration',
      fieldType: 'select',
      options: [ // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP TO CREATE AS MANY OPTIONS AS CREATED REUSABLE VARIABLES
        {
          "label": programTitle,
          "value": programId
        },
      ]
  },
  json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer in another forum so I thought I could paste it here for the help of the community.

original answer: https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/How-to-use-the-values-of-a-JSON-response-from-an-external/m-p/269841#M24366

In order to just get the data you need from what's being returned back to you, you can use some higher order functions such as map:

great youtube video on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRgD1yVwIvE

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

For example, if you have this data structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program2",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 2",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 1",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  }
]
```

you can use this code to map the objects into something more useful to you. First you can assign the data to a variable:

```
const myData = [
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program2",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 2",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "my-awesome-program1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "title": "My awesome program 1",
    "cookie_time": 45,
    "default_landing_page_url": "https://my-site.com"
  }
]
```

Then we can map over the data and assign it to a new variable or return it from a function:

```
const newData = myData.map(item => ({
   id: item.id,
   title: item.title
}))

// returns
// [
//   {
//     "id": "my-awesome-program2",
//     "title": "My awesome program 2"
//   },
//   {
//     "id": "my-awesome-program1",
//     "title": "My awesome program 1"
//   }
// ]
```

After this, if you need each item to then make a call to Hubspot, you can do that with whatever library you want like this:

```
   axios.post(url, config, item).then(res => {
       console.log("...Done!")
   })
});
```

It'd be best to put this code in a separate function after you've returned all of the data you need in order to ensure that all the data is there. I'd also recommend limiting your calls per second so you don't hit the X/s rate limit of the API. A good package for that is called bottleneck on NPM.